# Which is better adapted for global warming: deciduous or evergreen trees?

Tags: trees, global-warming

Evergreen photosynthesise for longer and don't lose their leaves all at once, whereas deciduous plants do and enter periods of hibernation during winter, among other differences (correct me if I am wrong).

Is there any significance in these differences considering the future impact of global warming on trees?

Comment: Please edit your question so it takes into account rules of thiw site http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask *there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”*

Comment: Which kind of tree do you see as you move towards the equator? That should give you a pretty good idea of what matters in warmer climates.